# How to create new list in C# without duplicate rows?

Tags: c#, sql, .net-6.0

**Objective:**  To create a new List that it will have unique objects and replace `roleId` with `List<int> RoleIds` and `roleName` replaced with `List<string> DisplayNames`

I am using .net 6 and C#12.

I manage to get data from the database, and it looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "user1.test@test.com",
    "firstName": "User1",
    "lastName": "Test1",
    "fullName": "User1 Test1",
    "roleId": 1,
    "roleName": "Member"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "email": "user2.test@test.com",
    "firstName": "User2",
    "lastName": "Test2",
    "fullName": "User2 Test2",
    "roleId": 1,
    "roleName": "Member"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "email": "user3.test@test.com",
    "firstName": "User3",
    "lastName": "Test3",
    "fullName": "User3 Test3",
    "roleId": 1,
    "roleName": "Member"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "email": "user1.test@test.com",
    "firstName": "User4",
    "lastName": "Test4",
    "fullName": "User4 Test4",
    "roleId": 1,
    "roleName": "Member"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "user1.test@test.com",
    "firstName": "User1",
    "lastName": "Test1",
    "fullName": "User1 Test1",
    "roleId": 2,
    "roleName": "Admin"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "email": "user1.test@test.com",
    "firstName": "User1",
    "lastName": "Test1",
    "fullName": "User1 Test1",
    "roleId": 2,
    "roleName": "Admin"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "email": "user3.test@test.com",
    "firstName": "User3",
    "lastName": "Test3",
    "fullName": "User3 Test3",
    "roleId": 2,
    "roleName": "Admin"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "email": "user4.test@test.com",
    "firstName": "User4",
    "lastName": "Test4",
    "fullName": "User4 Test4",
    "roleId": 2,
    "roleName": "Admin"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "user1.test@test.com",
    "firstName": "User1",
    "lastName": "Test1",
    "fullName": "User1 Test1",
    "roleId": 5,
    "roleName": "Super Admin"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "email": "user2.test@test.com",
    "firstName": "User2",
    "lastName": "Test2",
    "fullName": "User2 Test2",
    "roleId": 5,
    "roleName": "Super Admin"
  }
]
```

I have created a function, and I am using `StringBuilder` to construct a query and get data from the database.
I have created a new class `UserDetailsExtend` and I want to return a list of type `UserDetailsExtend`.

```cs
public class UserDetailsExtend
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? FullName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<int> RolesId { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    public List<string> DisplayName { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

```cs
public async Task<List<UserDetails>> GetUsersDetails()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT U.Id, U.Email, U.FirstName,  U.LastName, U.FullName, RU.RolesId, R.DisplayName ");

    sb.Append("FROM Users U ");
    sb.Append(" JOIN RoleUser RU ON RU.UsersId = U.Id ");
    sb.Append("  INNER JOIN Roles R ON RU.RolesId = R.Id ");

    return await WithConnection(async conn =>
    {
        var result = await conn.QueryAsync<UserDetails>(sb.ToString(), new { tenantId });
       //  **--->here I am getting duplicate rows.     
       // * *--->How to create a new list that will be of type List<UserDetailsExtend> and it will represent the structure in the Expected outcome below?


      return result.ToList();
    });
}
```

**[Expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmCob.png):**

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "user1.test@test.com",
    "firstName": "User1",
    "lastName": "Test1",
    "fullName": "User1 Test1",
    "roleIds": [ 1, 2, 5],
    "displayNames": ["Member", "Admin", "Super Admin" ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "email": "user2.test@test.com",
    "firstName": "User2",
    "lastName": "Test2",
    "fullName": "User2 Test2",
    "roleIds": [ 1, 2, 5 ],
    "displayNames": [ "Member", "Admin", "Super Admin" ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "email": "user3.test@test.com",
    "firstName": "User3",
    "lastName": "Test3",
    "fullName": "User3 Test3",
    "roleIds": [ 1, 2  ],
    "displayNames": [ "Member", "Admin" ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "email": "user1.test@test.com",
    "firstName": "User4",
    "lastName": "Test4",
    "fullName": "User4 Test4",
    "roleIds": [ 1, 2 ],
    "displayNames": [ "Member", "Admin" ]
  }  
]
```

The data is correct but I have multiple lines because a user can have many roles.

Comment: There are two problems: 1) the query is really trying to return *two* types and 2) the JSON doesn't match the query. It would be easier to have a `Roles` array whose objects have an ID and DisplayName. Dapper can return such classes easily with [multi-mapping](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper?tab=readme-ov-file#multi-mapping). You need multimapping even if you don't want an object array in JSON

Comment: Hashset removes dupes.

Comment: Sounds like a great case for linq to be honest

Comment: Would you mind sharing the original query?